# RDBMS to storage as json file Firebase

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Im working on a project that has a mobile and a website as the admin side. The mobile download 2 json file from the firebase storage. wordbank.json and update.json

I make use of the database to upload data. and when i need to make an update. i will convert the whole database to json file and store it in the storage as json file. i need to download it since i need to use the data offline and can be crud by the user.

is it possible to convert ur data in the database to json file and store it in its storage programmatically?

All i know is that you have an option in firebase that allows you to export you data to JSON. But i need to export the data to JSON programmatically. And then have it place in the storage.

is it possible? Can some enlighten me. Thank you to the kind souls who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you've stored the data in the Firebase Realtime Database, you can retrieve it in JSON format through [Firebase's REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data).

There is no feature to take a JSON file that is uploaded to Cloud Storage and then automatically add that to the Firebase Realtime Database. But since both products have well documented APIs, you can build such a feature yourself.